# Tables in databse don't connect with foreign keys

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have 4 entities listed below post. Clients and products are already in database. Problem is with Orders and OrdersProducts. I create Orders object, then I add client(which is already in database) and ArrayList of OrdersProducts, but I got error:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: pl.take.server.model.Orders.clients -> pl.take.server.model.Clients
```

When I don't add client, only ArrayList of OrderProducts it is in database but OrderProducts don't have foreign Key. What is wrong? I use Mysql server and hibernate.

```
@Entity
public class Clients implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private int idClient;
     private String clientName, clientSurname, clientCompany;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clients")
     private List<Orders> listOfOrders = new ArrayList<Orders>();
}

@Entity
public class Orders implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private int idOrder;
     private double totalAmount;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "idClientFK")
     private Clients clients;

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orders")
     private List<OrdersProducts> listOfProductsInOrder = new ArrayList<OrdersProducts>();
}

@Entity
public class OrdersProducts implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idOrderProduct;
    private int productAmount;
    private float productsValue;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idOrderFK")
    private Orders orders;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idProductFK")
    private Products products;
}

@Entity
public class Products implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idProduct;
    private String productName;
    private double productValuePerUnit;
    private String productUnit;
    private int productCount;
    private String productCompany;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "products")
    private List<OrdersProducts> listOfOrdersProducts = new ArrayList<OrdersProducts>();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have bidirectional relations, if you want to persist an Order you have to:

- Preconditions: You have a detached Client entity in a SesionScope bean and some detached Product entities in your WiewScoped backing bean.
- In your bussines method where you want to persist your order:

  - Create a new Order entity.
  - Update the "client <-> order" relations.
  - Create the OrderProducts entities, each per order line. Update the "order <- order line" relation for each OrderProducts entity: Add the Order to each OrderProducts. And update the "order line -> product" relation: Add the corresponding Product entity to the corresponding OrderProducts entity.
  - Get rid of "order line <- product", so unidirectional here.
  - Update the "order -> order lines" relation: Add each OrderProducts entity to the list in the Order entity.
- Now you have your new Order and OrderProducts entities with all the relations set. This is your model in the JSF framework.
- Now you only have to persist your Order entity, and then the order and its order lines will be persisted into the database, due to your cascade attribute in the "order -> order lines" relation.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bidirectional association Orders <-> Clients (bidirectional association is declared with `mappedBy` annotation attribute).

Hibernate does not know what object is the primary one.

You have two options:

1. Remove bidirectional association from one end and declare `@OneToMany` to be cascaded. (`@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL`)
2. Save the second object before assigning the reference.

Choosing the first option you will end with something like this:
...

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "idClientFK")
private List<Orders> listOfOrders = new ArrayList<Orders>();
```

and the saving logic would be something like this:

```
Clients client = new Client();
List<Orders> orders = new ArrayList<>();
orders.add(new Orders());
clients.setOrders(orders);
enityManager.save(clients);
```

Comment: When I remove `@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idClientFK")
    private Clients clients;` how hibernate will connect new Order with correct client when i add one?

Comment: So i guess that when I put new Orders i database I will also have to add that order to listOfOrders and then update client in database?

Comment: yup, that will be the second option

Comment: Hmm, lets stay in first option. I must set what you said in Clients entity and remove `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "idClientFK") private Clients clients;` And then I need to add Orders object and it will be connected? But how It will be know which clent? I don't have client in Orders object.

Comment: if you don't keep bidirectional association, you won't be able to know from the Order object to which Client it belongs

Comment: Better keep bidirectional. Oh, you have to add `referencedColumnName = "idEntity"` to all JoinColumn annotations (without the PK). If you have bidirectionals the you can persist the order simply persisting the Order entity. If you have unidirectional OneToMany you have to persist Client in order to Persist the new or modified Order. In relation with your last comment I think your question is about how Hibernate know which Client, the response is: Because you have to persist this Client, to persist the Order. And how Hib know the Order? Because you added to the list of orders of this client.

Comment: It still not working. I create Orders entity then to every OrderProducts i add  Products and at the end I add ArrayList of OrderProducts to Orders. And table looklike this: [link]http://imgur.com/YnuhFH8. Why?

Comment: Clients are working. They cascade add Orders and OrderProducts but when I add Product to OrdersProducts idProductFK is null. How should I add them that FK won't be null?

Comment: you should delete the bidirectional association from child objects as well. BTW, what are you modelling with OrderProducts? one order row? if so,  you should not link the order row to the product. Imagine you create an Order with many products. You save it. Everything looks OK for now. But hey! someone just modified a Product. Look, the order has changed!!

Comment: Two solutions, Funtik and mine, are valid, you decide to have bidirectional or not, or a mix. I advice you to experiment with both. In some cases a bidirectionel is weird and not a good idea, and in others is essential for implementing the requisites. @Funtik, linking the products to its order lines could be a good idea in some scenarios. Which data are worrying you to change in a product?

Comment: @lametaweb all data. I've been involved in several e-commerce projects. Every project makes a copy of product into OrderRow. Imagine you change some property (name of the product) and the client requests an invoice later. He gets the invoice with different products he has paid for

Comment: I understand the problem. Let's assume that nobody will change product :) I won't do that mistake in the future but now when i am learning I didn't notice that problem.

Comment: if you're doing your homework you can get some bonus points for implementing it right ;)

Comment: Yes, I know @Funtik. As said by pawkondr it is out of the scope of basics. You could also have product versions history and link to the current version.